# ReplyKeyboardMarkup selective Python не получается правильно написать

Tags: python, telebot

Мне нужно сделать так что бы при написании текста в чат "Tesla Bot", только человеку который написал выводились кнопки а не всем подряд, не понимаю как это реализовать подскажите есть такой код, пытался делать что то с Selective но как задать ему это не знаю

```py
if message.text == "Tesla Bot":
    ye = random.choice(["I'm here, as always:(", "Did you call me?"])
    bot_answers = random.choice(["something important or bored?", "what you wanted?"])
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Bot who are you?")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Bot why are you here?")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Let's really talk next time")

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True).add(item1, item2, item3)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "{0} <b>{1.first_name}</b> {2}".format(ye, message.from_user, bot_answers), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: в чат всмысле в ЛС или в группу?

Comment: Violet Ну в группе что бы когда человек писал заданное слово, кнопки в группе высвечивались только ему, а не всем кто в группе вот это не понимаю как реализовать если поможете будет хорошо)

Comment: В лс я знаю как сделать в send_message поменять message.from_user.id но мне нужно что бы это было в группе

Comment: https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/issues/875 не смотрите что там php

Comment: Violet 
У sendMessageметода нет selectiveпараметра, есть только клавиатура, которую вы правильно настраиваете. Это reply_to_message_idто, что обеспечивает то, что только пользователь, запросивший клавиатуру, видит ее. вот это там было написано а как мне это использовать?

Comment: А все большое Спасибо разобрался)))

Comment: будет здорово, если вы опубликуете ответ на свой вопрос с решением, это поможет другим пользователям.

Comment: Violet А как это сделать я без понятие просто